# Starting Minecraft via Batch script in maximized mode?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I've got it down to start minecraft with a batch script and auto-login.

```
start /high javaw -Xmx2048M -Xms1024M -Djava.library.path=bin/natives -cp bin/minecraft.jar;bin/jinput.jar;bin/lwjgl.jar;bin/lwjgl_util.jar net.minecraft.client.Minecraft "somebody" "password"
```

However I can't figure out how to start minecraft maximized. There's the magiclauncher which allows me to do that, but I do not want extra applications running when I don't have to. And just 1 simple function is not worth the extra application in my opinion.

So anyway, is there a way to start minecraft with a batch script maximized?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Batch files can only pass arguments to Java and Minecraft, and neither offer the option to start maximised. You will have to use an external program of *some* sort if you want it to maximise automatically. There are plenty of programs that will watch for a specific window and maximise it automatically, or wrap a program and maximise its window after launch, but there are too many to give a recommendation.

Aside, MagicLauncher doesn't keep running after it launches Minecraft. For just this one option I understand not wanting a whole new application to run, but it still running in the background isn't something you have to worry about.

Comment: Point is, it runs. In the background. I don't want nor do I need that for something like this. If it's not possible, then it's not possible. I'll just have to keep on clicking maximized after MC starts.

Comment: @NoCanDo It doesn't run in the background, that's what I'm saying. It works just like the vanilla launcher: starts the minecraft.jar and then terminates itself.